# Update records of foreign key, if one record is updated

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

This table **children table** has relation with **father table**. So, if I update a record in "children table" for example *name*, then all *name* attribute records should be updated too.

```
DB::table('data_anak')->where('bapak_id', $id)->update([
            'nama' => $request->nama_anak,
            'jenis_kelamin' => $request->gender_anak, 
            'tempat_tgl_lahir' => $request->tmt, 
            'tgl_baptis' => $request->baptis_anak, 
            'tgl_sidi' => $request->sidi_anak, 
        ]);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Why is there the need to cascade changes? This can be avoided by having the data in a single table? Your need can be addressed using triggers/cascading updates